# How can I install Java 8u65 on a Windows Server?

Tags: windows, java, installation

If you attempt to install the Java 8u65 runtime on a Windows Server, the following error message appears:

> Content within this application coming from the website listed below is being blocked by Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration

[image: Content within this application coming from the website listed below is being blocked by Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration]

When the dialog is dismissed, the installer hangs.  I tried adding the file to the Trusted sites zone, but I couldn't figure out how to properly format the path.

How can I install the Java 8u65 runtime on my Windows Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest workaround is to perform a silent install from the command line:

```
start /wait jre-8u65-windows-i586.exe /s REBOOT=0
```

Another possibility would be to temporarily [disable Enhanced Security Configuration](http://blogs.technet.com/b/chenley/archive/2011/03/10/how-to-turn-off-ie-esc.aspx).

(NB: Oracle have accepted a bug report, [JDK-8140197](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8140197).)

Comment: Silent mode works like a charm on Windows Server 2012 R2, also with x64  version +1

Comment: Thank you for that answer, going to do more silent installs :-) I have just included a link to disable ESC incase you are 2012+ http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/11/28/how-to-disable-ie-enhanced-security-in-windows-server-2012/